# Selenium Get Element After Following Link

Tags: javascript, selenium

all!
I've followed as many tips and tutorials as I can, but I can't figure out how to obtain an element in Node JS Selenium after moving from the starting page.

In my use case, I go to a login screen, enter the pertinent information, and then run a click() on the login button. I am taken to the home screen.

After this, I cannot select any elements! I just keep getting 'not found' warnings.

I'm sleeping for 6000ms, and I have set the implicit timeouts to 30s.

What am I missing here?
My problematic part would be in the function GoToSettings, which is called after the Login button is clicked.

Thanks

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
By = webdriver.By,
until = webdriver.until;
const TIMEOUT = 30
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
const capabilities = driver.getCapabilities().then(()=>{
    capabilities['map_'].set('timeouts', { implicit: TIMEOUT, pageLoad: TIMEOUT, script: TIMEOUT });
});

var info = require('./info.json')

driver.get('http://www.okcupid.com/settings?')
driver.sleep(2000);


//We may already be logged in at this point
driver.getTitle().then((title) => {
    driver.getCurrentUrl().then((url) => {
        LoginOrHome(title, url);
    });
});

function LoginOrHome(title, url){
    if(title == "Free Online Dating | OkCupid" || url == "https://www.okcupid.com/login?p=/settings") {
        //needslogin.exe
        console.log("Logging in!");
        login();
    } else if (title == "Welcome! | OkCupid" || url == "https://www.okcupid.com/settings?") {
        //We are already logged in
        console.log("Already logged in. Changing location.");
        goToSettings();
    } else {
        console.log(title);
        console.log(url);
    }
}

function goToSettings() {
    driver.sleep(6000);
    driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle()).then( () => {
        driver.getCurrentUrl().then((title) => {
            //This prints the URL of the previous page
            console.log(title);
        });
    })
    
}

function login(){
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(info.email).then(() => {
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(info.password).then(() => {
            driver.findElement(By.css("div > input[type=submit]")).click().then(()=> { goToSettings() });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: *What am I missing here* You are missing the html and the code. Please add them to your question.

Comment: You shouldn't use explicit `sleep` command in your e2e tests, instead, try using https://angular.io/api/core/Testability#whenstable

Comment: I will add the code presently

Comment: are you testing an SPA using a js framework?

Comment: No. I'm just running the node code client-side.